# How can make a function which take View and returns custom result in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want build a function stand alone from ContentView which I could use this func to initialize some value, for example in this down code I want get size of View with the function, but for unknown reason for me it returns zero, I think the background modification do not work as I wanted in this build. any help?

```
  func viewSizeReaderFunction<Content: View>(content: Content) -> CGSize {
    
    var sizeOfView: CGSize = CGSize()
    
    content
        .background(
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Color
                    .clear
                    .onAppear() { sizeOfView =  geometry.size }
                
            })

    return sizeOfView

 }
```

---

```
let sizeOfText: CGSize = viewSizeReaderFunction(content: Text("Hello, world!"))
```

---

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Color.red
            .onAppear() {
                print(sizeOfText)
            }

    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general idea is to have the view report its size using `preference`, and create a view modifier to capture that. But, like @RobNapier said, the struct has to be in the view hierarchy, and so within a rendering context, to be able to talk about sizes.

```
struct SizeReporter: ViewModifier {
   @Binding var size: CGSize
   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
      content
         .background(GeometryReader { geo in
             Color.clear
                  .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geo.size)
         })
         .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: { value in
             size = value
         })
   }
}
```

And we'd need to define `SizePreferenceKey`:

```
extension SizeReporter {
   private struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
      static let defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
      static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
         value = nextValue()
      }
   }
}
```

You could create a convenience method on `View`:

```
extension View {
   func getSize(_ size: Binding<CGSize>) -> some View {
      self.modifier(SizeReporter(size: size))
   }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
@State var size: CGSize = .zero

var body: some View {
   Text("hello").getSize($size)
}
```

Comment: All your code is understandable for my, @RobNapier  build kind of ViewModifier and the function that use that ViewModifier together in just 1 custom function, but why you used PreferenceKey? I think the Binding would be cover what we needed, can you explain plz?

Comment: Unlike with `.onAppear`, preference allows you to capture changes in the size, say if you have `Text(text).getSize($size)` and also `TextField("", text: $text)`, the every time you type, `size` would change

Comment: Now I can see what you done, to be frankly I never used any other ways than onAppear or onChange, Please correct me if I am wrong, I think your way of using **PreferenceKey** is much secure and guaranteed to getting the value that we were looking for. right?

Comment: @swiftPunk, I think it depends on what you need. `onAppear` gives you the initial size. This allows you to track the changes. You can modify this to use a callback instead of a binding, if you want.

Comment: the way you solved the problem is interesting for me, because you explicitly says to SwiftUI what you looking for, and there is no place for mistake or get corrupted in the way that happens onAppear, for this reason I think **PreferenceKey** is must better option than onAppear, and thank you to teaching and showing the best ways.

Answer (score 3):

Views are just data that describe view layout. They are not objects that represent the actual "view" in the way that UIView is. They do not have their own logic or state (which is why they require `@State` variables rather than just `var`).

The code you've written assigns a zero-size to `sizeOfView`, then creates a View struct that is immediately thrown away, and then returns `sizeOfView`. There is nothing that evaluates the View struct. I would expect that the compiler is giving you a warning about this, something like "result of call to background is unused."

The way you do what you're describing is with Preferences, `.onPreferenceChange` and usually `@State`. There are a lot of answers to that around Stack Overflow.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui%5D+size+of+view

Here's one example, note in particular the use of `.hidden()`:

```
extension View {
    func saveSize(handler: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        return self
            .background(
                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    Color.clear
                        .onAppear {
                            handler(geometry.size)
                        }
                })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var sizeOfText: CGSize = .zero

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        Color.red
            .onAppear() {
                print(sizeOfText)
            }
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .hidden()
                .saveSize { sizeOfText = $0 }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this code is slightly dangerous in that it relies on the order that `onAppear` gets called, and that's not promised. In practice, you generally need to handle the case where the size hasn't been set yet. This can be made more robust with Preferences, but that tends to be a lot of hassle.

Comment: I have zero issue to getting my Views size in normal way that we use it as you said, I wanted to test another way like I asked about in question, the reason that I am trying to make this happen, was this: I just need that value not that View, I can make that happen in normal way in content View, but that means it always attached to app or my Content View even if we make it Color.Clear and we do not see it, but it is there for just reading a value! that is why I thought to make it stand alone! run func! get answer, bye bye not needed View!

Comment: That's not possible. A View does not have a size outside of a rendering context, and you cannot create a rendering context, nor do you have access to one at runtime.

Comment: `Text("Hello, world!")` doesn't *have* an intrinsic size. It depends on the current environment (what is the current Font?) and it depends on what space is offered to it (your code doesn't offer any space). Those don't exist inside a View; they exist inside the rendering context.

Comment: for security of having right answer for **sizeOfText** we can use onChange as well to being sure that we got the size. right? because it is SwiftUI it can render Color.red first and onAppear then it goes for Text! This was just an example that I wanted cover onAppear issue, but in the fact Swift Render from Bottom to Top! because Text is closer to screen and in this case we should have always answer in calling onAppear because text already got rendered! right?

Comment: There are no promises about any of that. The order that `onAppear` methods get called is undefined.

Comment: thanks for your teaching and information, I voted and I decided PreferenceKey is better way than I was using, but your custom func was very interesting, I just learn  it from you.